# A good translation for 寒がるふり / 冷めたふり / etc?

Tags: translation, idioms

Every once in a while, I come across [some variant](https://www5.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/35764.html) of [a phrase](https://www24.atwiki.jp/utauuuta/pages/3519.html) that would literally translate to "pretending to be cold."

As far as I can tell, it refers to a sort of desperate attention-seeking behavior; something like, the speaker feels alone and unsupported, so they play up how much they need help and how sad they are to see if anyone will come and comfort them. Like, they want to feel like someone is there for them if they need it.

While I feel like I more-or-less understand the phrase itself, I can't figure out how to express it concisely in English. It's usually sufficient to translate it literally because it usually makes sense in context, but sometimes the existing context isn't quite enough. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: crocodile tears? no... that's usually used with fake grief apparently... hmmm..

Comment: throwing a pity party, maybe? playing the sympathy card? fake tears? turning on the waterworks...  I might suggest asking this question in an English stack exchange site, since you don't really want help with Japanese but with a way to say a certain thing in English...

Comment: @ericfromabeno yeah, that's probably a good idea. I'll do that, thanks.

Comment: I don't know how it should be translated, but 寒がるふり means that you behave as if you felt a chill while actually you don't. 冷めたふり means that you behave as if you were not into it while actually you are interested in it.